# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskAgentPoolNotFoundException: No agent pool found with identifier 13

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to register the agent in server to create Deployment Groups for Azure DevOps Release pipeline using the provided PowerShell script(Azure DevOps Portal). Script is able to download the azagent, but throwing the below error while configuring the agent:

Error:

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskAgentPoolNotFoundException: No agent pool found with identifier 13.
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpMethod method, IEnumerable`1 additionalHeaders, Guid locationId, Object routeValues, ApiResourceVersion version, HttpContent content, IEnumerable`1 queryParameters, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.DeploymentGroupAgentConfigProvider.AddAgentAsync(AgentSettings agentSettings, TaskAgent agent, CommandSettings command)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConfigureAsync(CommandSettings command)

Comment: It is working fine for another servers, default agent pools online(green), but no idea, why is it not working in a particular server.

Comment: Sorry to say, but did not get any solution till now :(.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#creating-agent-pools):

> You're a member of a project and you want to use a set of machines owned by your team for running build and deployment jobs. First, make sure you're a member of a group in All Pools with the Administrator role.

Based on the error message, it seems that the agent pool couldn't be found. So you could check your permission for the target Deployment Group pool in `Collection Settings -> Deployment Pools-> Security`.

You could grant the `Administrator` permission for your account. Then you could check if it could work.

[image]

Here is [a ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-create-agent-poolin-azure-devops/609794#T-N610417) with the similar issue, you could refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for reply Kevin. This configuration is for on-premises, and it working fine for other server, I am getting this error only in one server. I am admin and having all the required permission to register the Agent and creation of deployment group.

Comment: Could you please share the version of other server? What method did you use for authentication? You could try to add `--token <token>` to use Personal Access Token as auth method